# How to import jQuery npm module in TypeScript 1.8

Tags: typescript, npm, ecmascript-6

First of all, I'm struggling to ask the right question. I feel like I've missed or mixed some concepts regarding TypeScript compiler, new ES2015 (ES6) module syntax and module loaders.

I'm trying to import npm installed jquery module using ES2015 module syntax. Typescript should transpile it to ES5.

I get an error when opening index.html.

```
system-polyfills.src.js:1276 Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
Evaluating http://localhost:3000/jquery
Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
```

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bare TypeScript</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <div>Loading...</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

- I'm not sure if `<script
  src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>` is necessary.
- How come that B import works ok when `console.log($)` is commented
  out? jQuery import should work too?
- Maybe mixing npm's commonjs modules with systemjs is the problem?

main.ts

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'
import B from './app.b'

console.log("Monkey");
let b = new B();
console.log($);
```

How to configure tsc to work with ES2015 module syntax?
TypeScript 1.8 is used.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.25"
  },
```

typings.json

```
{
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts#7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd",
    "jquery": "registry:dt/jquery#1.10.0+20160316155526"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to load jQuery as a systemjs module, but it's AMD.
Also, unless you have a default export on your `app.b`, typescript compiler will throw an error. Did you check if you are getting any compiler errors?

This [Github](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/844) has some insight on loading jQuery using ES6 import syntax.

Comment: I don't get compiler errors. When commenting out `console.log($)` "monkey" text is written out to console. Thx for GitHub link.